# Rust Adding Schnorr Dependency

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo

I am trying to add Schnorr for my Rust project.
https://docs.rs/schnorr/latest/schnorr/signature/struct.Signature.html

But in Cargo.toml, when I add `schnorr = "0.0.20"` and try to run `cargo.run`, I am getting this error:

```
 Compiling subtle v2.5.0                                                                                                                       
   Compiling arrayvec v0.5.2

    error: could not compile `rayon-core`
    
    Caused by:
      process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name rayon_core --edition=2021 C:\Users\write\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\rayon-core-1.11.0\src\lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=144 --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=7bf9cbb0e7c694de -C extra-filename=-7bf9cbb0e7c694de --out-dir
```

After that I am getting this:

```
error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
   --> C:\Users\write\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\packed_simd_2-0.3.8\src\lib.rs:214:1
    |
214 | / #![feature(
215 | |     adt_const_params,
216 | |     repr_simd,
217 | |     rustc_attrs,
...   |
224 | |     custom_inner_attributes,
225 | | )]
    | |__^

error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
   --> C:\Users\write\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\packed_simd_2-0.3.8\src\lib.rs:219:5
    |
219 |     stdsimd,
    |     ^^^^^^^

error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
   --> C:\Users\write\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\packed_simd_2-0.3.8\src\lib.rs:222:5
    |
222 |     core_intrinsics,
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0554`.
error: could not compile `packed_simd_2` due to 3 previous errors
```

Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Try updating your Rust toolchain `rustup update` and `cargo clean` in the build directory, then `cargo run` again.

Comment: I did already but didnt work. Is it because my antivirus is blocking something? Because everytime I try to run cargo run, I am getting the message "suspecious program" from rust

Comment: Didn't work... is what exactly? ˋrustup updateˋ should work. Maybe reinstall if it is very, very old. You need at least v1.59.0 for Rayon. ˋrustc -versionˋ in cargo project dir tells which compiler is used.

Comment: Ya I reinstalled it. Plus I changed to a different crate because this one had unstable releases. Now its working.